# Missing property in resourceVisualization in Trending endpoint

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

The documentation for [resourceVisualization](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/insights_resourcevisualization) resource type ([Trending](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/insights_trending) endpoint) says that one of the properties that gets returned as part of the object is `type`.

However, when I use [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to test the endpoint I don't see this property. Is it going to be added soon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that identified and we are working on updating the API schema to have that property available by the end of next week.

Mario

Comment: Any progress on this issue?